# Connecting data from one route to another in Flask and inputting the data into the SQL table with SQL-alchemy

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a Flask web app. I'm running into a hiccup connecting the data captured from one page to the next page. I can input data for the address captured from 'address.html' through the notice route into table 1("locations"). But I can't seem to pull the data from the 'notice.html', which captures a submit type button value and is supposed to input it into table 2 ("notice_types") along with the foreign key. Immediately below are the SQL tables and further down are the routes and html pages.

```
class Address (db.Model):
    __tablename__="locations"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    notice_types = db.relationship("Notice", backref="locations", lazy=True)

    def add_notice(self, notice):
        n = Notice(notice=notice, address_id=self.id)
        db.session.add(n)
        db.session.commit()


class Notice (db.Model):
    __tablename__="notice_types"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    notice = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("locations.id"), nullable=False
```

Routes:

```
  @app.route('/')
def location():
    return render_template('address.html')



@app.route('/notice', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def notice():

    location = Address.query.all()

    address = request.form.get('address')
    if not address:
        return render_template("error.html")

    location = Address(address=address)
    db.session.add(location)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('notice.html', address=address, location=location)


@app.route('/action', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def action():

    notice = request.form.get('first_n')
    try: 
        address_id = request.args.get("address", None)
    except ValueError: 
        return render_template("error.html")

    address = Address.query.get(address_id)
    if not address: 
        return render_template("error.html")


    notice_type = Notice(notice=notice, address=address)
    db.session.add(location)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('thirtysixty.html', address=address)
```

Below are samples of the two html pages:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('notice') }}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label align='left' class='thick'>Address: </label>
    <br>
    <input list="locations" name="address" id="address" type="text" placeholder="street, 
     city, state, zip code">
</div>
 <p class='a'> 123 Example Southeast, Oakland, CA, 94590</p>
<div class="form-group">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" minlength="6">Submit</button>




<form action="{{ url_for('action') }}" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class='button' name="first_n" value="3/6 Notice" id="go">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question:

The SQL tables should stay as they are. Instead I needed to execute the correct db query in the notice route and use jina2 properly in the highlighted template. Below is the fixed code; again it goes over how to properly move form data from one route to another through the use of templates and jinja2. Using these lines I was able to input the data into both SQL tables along with the correct keys.

```
@app.route('/')
def location():
    return render_template('address.html')

@app.route("/notice", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def notice():

    address = request.form.get("address")
    if not address:
       return render_template("error.html")

    db.execute("INSERT INTO locations (address) VALUES (:address)",
           {"address": address})
    db.commit()
    addresses = db.execute("SELECT * FROM locations).fetchall()
    return render_template("notice.html", addresses=addresses) 


  @app.route('/action', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
      def action():

    notice = request.form.get('first_n')
    try: 
        address_id = request.form.get("address_id")
    except ValueError: 
        return render_template("error.html")

   db.execute("INSERT INTO notice_types (notice, address_id) VALUES 
   (:notice, :address_id)", {"notice":notice, "address_id":address_id})
   db.commit()
   return render_template("action.html")
```

The fixed HTML: 
*The first template highlighted in the question is fine. Below is the template that needed to be fixed.*

```
<form action="{{ url_for('action') }}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
      {% for address in addresses %}
         <input type="hidden" name="address_id" value="{{address.id}}">
      {% endblock %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class='button' name="first_n" value="3/6 
           Notice" data-value="3/6 notice">
      </div>
    </form>
```